# awk to process multiple lines and return several strings

Tags: awk

I have these strings:

```
  Certificate Name: domain1.com
    Serial Number: 37aadb8fae7b908e1228c3e71
    Domains: domain1.com www.domain1.com
    Expiry Date: 2022-11-20 02:14:29+00:00 (VALID: 3 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: www.domain2
    Serial Number: 37aadb8fae7b908e1228c3e72
    Domains: www.domain2
    Expiry Date: 2021-10-19 02:15:45+00:00 (INVALID: EXPIRED)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain2/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain2/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: domain3.com
    Serial Number: 37aadb8fae7b908e1228c3e73
    Domains: domain3.com www.domain3.com
    Expiry Date: 2022-12-17 02:11:37+00:00 (VALID: 30 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain3.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain3.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: domain4.com
    Serial Number: 37aadb8fae7b908e1228c3e74
    Domains: domain4.com www.domain4.com
    Expiry Date: 2022-12-10 02:08:54+00:00 (VALID: 23 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain4.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain4.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: domain5.com
    Serial Number: 37aadb8fae7b908e1228c3e75
    Domains: domain5.com www.domain5.com
    Expiry Date: 2022-11-20 02:14:37+00:00 (VALID: 3 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain5.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain5.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: domain6.com
    Serial Number: 37aadb8fae7b908e1228c3e76
    Domains: domain6.com www.domain6.com
    Expiry Date: 2022-11-10 02:11:32+00:00 (INVALID: EXPIRED)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain6.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain6.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: domain7.com
    Serial Number: 37aadb8fae7b908e1228c3e77
    Domains: domain7.com www.domain7.com
    Expiry Date: 2020-05-31 23:50:48+00:00 (INVALID: EXPIRED)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain7.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain7.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: domain8.com
    Serial Number: 37aadb8fae7b908e1228c3e78
    Domains: domain8.com www.domain8.com
    Expiry Date: 2022-11-28 02:14:42+00:00 (VALID: 11 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain8.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain8.com/privkey.pem
```

I'm used to using sed, but I know it will only process line by line.

I've been trying to use awk for a while, but since I'm not familiar with it, I'm still struggling. But, I'm also open to other suggestions.

I just want to look for the keyword `INVALID: EXPIRED` and then return the domain name at the next line, and finally, it should have this output:

```
www.domain2
domain6.com
domain7.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick I think:

```
awk '/INVALID: EXPIRED/{getline;split($0,line,"/");print line[5]}'
```

Comment: Awesome, it works, thanks!